# "wiki is currently unable to handle this request" after installing SimpleMathJax on MediaWiki

Tags: php, javascript, mediawiki

I need to show mathematical terms in `mediawiki-1.26.2` so I tried to install [`SimpleMathJax`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SimpleMathJax) on `mediawiki`. I followed the described in extension page:

I downloaded SimpleMathJax-master.zip then extract, rename it to SimpleMathJax and move it to extensions directory of mediawiki.
I added these lines to LocalSettings.php:

```
# End of automatically generated settings.
# Add more configuration options below.
require_once "$IP/extensions/SimpleMathJax/SimpleMathJax.php";
$wgSimpleMathJaxSize = 120;
```

But when I want to browse to the Wiki, I get this error:

```
wiki is currently unable to handle this request.
```

Also I tried to replace `require_once "$IP/extensions/SimpleMathJax/SimpleMathJax.php";` line with `wfLoadExtension( 'SimpleMathJax' );` but problem remains.

Comment: That extension doesn't have a `extension.json` file, so you'll have to use the `require_once` method of enabling it. (Not that this helps with figuring out your problem.)

Comment: @SamWilson It seems you say that I should not replace  `require_once ...` with `wfLoadExtension...` . But how I can solve this problem?

Comment: That's correct. And to solve your problem, you need to figure out what the actual error is. So make sure you've got all error output turned on; see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug for more details.

Comment: @SamWilson I read that article and will tell you the result.

Answer (score -1):

See the [debugging manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug) on how to find out what your error is.

Comment: A link to a manual is never a high quality answer.  At the very least you should explain the relevant steps in your answer and provide the link for reference.   See: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)